# Redundant indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table containing the following three indexes:

Index #1:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_1] 
     ON [dbo].[TABLE] ([A] ASC, [B] ASC, [C] ASC)
```

Index #2:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_2] 
    ON [dbo].[TABLE] ([A] ASC, [B] ASC)
```

Index #3:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_3] 
    ON [dbo].[TABLE] ([C] ASC, [B] ASC, [A] ASC)
```

If my humble understanding is correct, then the following holds:

1. I could remove `IDX_2` as it its fully contained in `IDX_1` (same columns in same order).
2. `IDX_1` and `IDX_3` are not the same. `IDX_1` can be used for queries against column `A` or for queries against column `A` and column `B`. On the other hand `IDX_3` can be used for queries against column `C` or columns `C` and `B`. Both indexes are equivalent useful for queries against all three columns `A, B, C`.
3. `IDX_2` and `IDX_3` cover `IDX_1`. For queries against column `A` or columns `A` and `B` `IDX_2` will be used and for queries against all three columns `IDX_3` can be used. So it is safe to remove `IDX_1`.

Thanks in advance,
Malte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of all your questions, i would remove idx_2 since,that is redundant due to Indx_1

For Questions 2 and 3,which covers below indexes,they are not redundant,if your queries follow some specific pattern like below

```
  indx-2    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_1] ON [dbo].[TABLE] (
              [A] ASC,
              [B] ASC,
              [C] ASC)



  indx-3       CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_3] ON [dbo].[TABLE] (
              [C] ASC,
              [B] ASC,
              [A] ASC)
```

below query can  use indx2 efficiently,but not index3

```
select a,b,c from table where a=20 and b=40 and c>40
```

Below query can use index3 efficiently,but index2 won't be of much help

```
select a,b,c from table where c=20 and b=40 and a>90
```

If your queries wont follow this pattern and  if all they do is searching for equality ,then one of them is redundant